# Sql Table Query

Tags: sql

I have following table with duplicate records.I want to retrieve record with duplicate id but different name,date.

```
CREATE TABLE Student1
    (`id` int,`status` int,`amount` int , `Name` varchar(10), `date` varchar(55))
;
    INSERT INTO Student1
    (`id`,`status`,`amount`, `Name`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1,0,4500, 'ram', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,2000, 'shyam', '05/09/2013'),
    (4,0,1500, 'ghanshyam', '08/11/2014'),
    (3,0,4500, 'gopal', '04/02/2012'),
    (2,0,8000, 'radheshyam', '15/11/2013'),
    (4,1,1500, 'ghanshyam', '18/10/2015'),
     (1,1,4500, 'ram', '14/02/2012'),
    (2,0,6500, 'radhe', '11/11/2014'),
    (3,1,4500, 'gopal', '14/02/2015')
;
```

Expected Result:

```
     id status    amount     Name        date
       2    0       2000      shyam      05/09/2013
       2    0       8000    radheshyam   15/11/2013
       2    0       6500      radhe      11/11/2014
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Student1 GROUP BY id HAVING count(*)>1

Comment: Output:
id status amount Name date
1 0 4500 ram 04/02/2012
2 0 2000 shyam 05/09/2013
3 0 4500 gopal 04/02/2012
4 0 1500 ghanshyam 08/11/2014

Comment: Put all you additional information inside your question (use [edit]).

Comment: Based on your syntax, you seem to be using MySQL, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Student1
where id in
(
  select id from Student1
  group by id
  having count(distinct name) > 1
  and count(distinct date) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks juergen_d it works,but i want to check name and date both

Comment: Then add `and count(distinct date) > 1`